# jquery events not firing on returning back to a page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a mobile application which uses ajax for fetching data and showing that on screen. The application works fine.

I have a *search_member* page. when i click a button, it shows a list of customers, on clicking each customer, it goes to a details page and there is a button on the details page which navigates to *create_new_ loan* page to fill in some info.

I am using a side panel menu in all the pages.

```
  <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../View/CreateNewLoan_tablet.html">New Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="../View/Search_tablet.html">Member Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

When I select the *Member Search* menu, its navigating to that page, but the document.ready() or button click events on that page are not firing.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            debugger;
});
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Do you mean `$(document).ready()` ? Can you post that function code

Comment: do you have jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: Is the code in this example from the page where the events are not firing? or from the page that links to it. This is not currently a complete example either way.

Comment: do you see any errors in console? are you sure that include jQuery in this page?